# How to import multiple locations to PYTHONPATH (bash)

Tags: python, bash, pythonpath

I know you can add multiple locations to python path by separating them by colons ie:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/one/location:~/second/location
```

etc.

I have several locations to add and it looks messy using the above method. Is there a way of adding them in multiple lines? This is what I tried and the last line erases the first.

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/one/location
export PYTHONPATH=~/second/location
```

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
PYTHONPATH=~/one/location:$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=~/second/location:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH
```

Note the order here: I've made them so that each has higher precedence than the one before; you could switch what goes on each side of the colon if you want later entries to have lower precedence.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are exporting from different files, called one after another:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/one/location:${PYTHONPATH}
```

and

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/second/location:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have many such paths, you can store them in array

```
declare -a array
array[0]=~/one/location 
array[1]=~/two/location 
array[2]=.....
export PYTHONPATH=$(printf "%s:${PYTHONPATH}" ${array[@]})
```